# how to add import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors} to package dependencies

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark from spark-shell. I used following command to add linalg package, but its not working.

```
  spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark.ml.linalg
```

Need correct command to add linalg package

Answer (score 0):

you should provide group id and version also along with artifact id below is the example

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:2.1.0
```

the format is

```
--packages groupid:artifactid:version
```

Comment: But I tried looking for group id and version. I am not able to find it